# Error while updating property 'accessibilityState' of a view managed by: RCTView Value for disable cannot be cast from ReadableNativeMap to Boolean

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

```
Error while updating property 'accessibilityState' of a view managed by: RCTView 

null

Value for disable cannot be cast from ReadableNativeMap to Boolean.
```

This message occurred when this code snippet executed

```js
  const onCheck = async () => {
    if (!itemQuestion?.answer && itemQuestion?.type !== 'sorting_choice') {
      Alert.alert('', t('learningScreen.quiz.checkAlert'));
      return;
    }

    setIsLoading(true);
    const itemTemp = new Object() as any;

    if (itemQuestion?.type === 'sorting_choice') {
      itemTemp.value = itemQuestion?.options.map((y: any) => y.value);
    } else if (itemQuestion?.answer) {
      if (itemQuestion?.type === 'true_or_false') {
        itemTemp.value = itemQuestion?.answer.value;
      } else if (itemQuestion?.type === 'fill_in_blanks') {
        itemTemp.value = itemQuestion?.answer;
      } else if (itemQuestion?.type === 'multi_choice') {
        itemTemp.value = itemQuestion?.answer.map((y: any) => y.value);
      } else {
        itemTemp.value = itemQuestion?.answer.map((y: any) => y.value);
      }
    }
    const param = {
      id: item?.id,
      question_id: itemQuestion?.id,
      answered: itemTemp?.value,
    };

    const checkAnswerPayload = await checkAnswer(param, token, navigation);
    if (checkAnswerPayload?.code === 'cannot_check_answer') {
      Alert.alert(checkAnswerPayload?.message || "");
    }
    console.log(checkAnswerPayload)
    const dataTemp = {
      id: itemQuestion?.id,
      result: checkAnswerPayload.result,
      explanation: checkAnswerPayload?.explanation || "",
    };
    itemCheck.push(dataTemp);
    setItemCheck((prevItemCheck) => [...prevItemCheck, dataTemp])

    setIsLoading(false);
  };
```

Expected to work correctly, but shows the above error.

Comment: This error usually comes from passing the wrong props - can you show your UI code please